# Why is my CSRF token invalid? I already set it in my angular app

Tags: java, angular, spring-security

I have tried the login process manually with insomnia. I am able to login and logout so long as I set `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. [image]

But when I try to do it in my angular app, I am unable to login even if I already setup the
`X-CSRF-TOKEN`. Why is this happening? I checked the request and I can see the token there.

[image]

The request doesn't even enter my login method. It just says that CSRF token is invalid, when it is perfectly valid. I am getting the token generated from this method in my controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/csrf")
    public CsrfResponse getCsrf(HttpServletRequest request) {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");
        log.info("Returning token: {}", csrfToken.getToken());
        return new CsrfResponse(csrfToken.getToken());
    }
```

Here's my login method:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public CurrentUser login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest request,
                             BindingResult bindingResult,
                             HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                             HttpServletResponse response) throws LoginException {

        log.info("header: {}", httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN"));

        if (httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
            throw new LoginException("Please logout first.");
        }

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new LoginException("Invalid username or password.");
        }

        try {
            httpServletRequest.login(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword());
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            throw new LoginException("Invalid username or password.");
        }

        Authentication auth = (Authentication) httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();
        User user = (User) auth.getPrincipal();
        String csrfToken = httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN");

        log.info("User {} logged in.", user.getUsername());
        rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(httpServletRequest, response, auth);
        return new CurrentUser(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), csrfToken);
    }
```

Here's my configuration:

```
    @Bean("securityFilterChain")
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        CookieCsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        csrfTokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
        csrfTokenRepository.setHeaderName("X-CSRF-TOKEN");

        DefaultSecurityFilterChain chain = http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(customizer -> customizer
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/csrf").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/v1/destination").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/v1/destination/featured").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/v1/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/v1/destination").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().denyAll()
                )
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository))
                .exceptionHandling(customizer -> customizer
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                )
                .rememberMe(customizer -> customizer.alwaysRemember(true).key("remember"))
                .build();

        RememberMeServices rememberMeServices = http.getSharedObject(RememberMeServices.class);
        beanFactory.registerSingleton("rememberMeServices", rememberMeServices);

        return chain;
    }
```

Here's the interceptor I created that attaches the `X-CSRF-TOKEN`.

```
@Injectable()
export class CsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private headerService: CsrfService) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        
        const csrfToken = this.headerService.getCsrfToken();

        const modifiedRequest = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        
        return next.handle(modifiedRequest);
    }
}
```

I don't understand, from my perspective, I should be able to login successfully. But why am I getting this error instead?

```
2023-08-03T02:49:09.572+08:00 DEBUG 94056 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-08-03T02:49:10.657+08:00 DEBUG 94056 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/v1/login
2023-08-03T02:49:10.660+08:00 DEBUG 94056 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/api/v1/login
2023-08-03T02:49:10.660+08:00 DEBUG 94056 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
2023-08-03T02:49:10.664+08:00 DEBUG 94056 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2023-08-03T02:49:10.667+08:00 DEBUG 94056 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error
2023-08-03T02:49:10.682+08:00 DEBUG 94056 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
```

I've been trying to solve this for 2 days already! I don't get it! I am on angular 15, and spring security 6.1.0.